# Display all occurences if the count is 0 in a specific attribute

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table like this :

```
date_col1   col2

01/10/2000   a
01/10/2000   a
02/10/2000   b
02/10/2000   b
03/10/2000   c
```

This,i would like to do is to count a specific element from col2 for each day.

So,i have tried to do something like that in order to find the occurrence of **a** :

```
select date_col1,
       count(date_col1)
from table
where col2=a
group by date_col1
order by date_col1
```

but there,i want to ask if there is possible to get 0 as count(date_col1) from other elements which have b or c value.

So,the desirable output will be :

```
01/10/2000   2
02/10/2000   0
03/10/2000   0
```

How can i implement this?

I am using oracle database 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to do a conditinal counting:

```
select date_col1,
       count(case when col2 = 'a' then 1 end)
from table
group by date_col1
order by date_col1
```